# how to dynamically replace css?

Tags: javascript, css

I've got an image on the page (class='image') within the div (class='galleria_wrapper') and want to place a caption (class='caption') at the lower right corner under that image.

The image could be vertical or horizontal, and making a fixed padding-right value let's say

```
.caption<{float:right;padding-top:5px;padding-right:90px;}
```

is not working for one or another. I need to switch on the fly *padding-right* value depending on horizontal or vertical image is currently on the page. I can theoretically access image's width through document.getElementByName('image').width although don't understand where to put that code. So, I probably need something like that:

```
document.getElementByClass('caption').padding-right = 
    (document.getElementByName('galleria_wrapper').width - 
    document.getElementByName('image').width)/2
```

Where do I put this code?

I do have that in my css file:

```
.caption{float:right;padding-top:5px;}
```

which places the caption below the image, but to far to the right (div 'galleria_wrapper' is wider than most of the images supposed to be displayed within that area).

I have an img tag in the html:

```
<img src=image title='this is caption' /></li>
```

...and some JavaScript which makes title displayed styled by the "caption" css definition.

How do I assign variable value for the padding-right without in-advance knowledge of particular image's width?

Comment: It sounds like you're overcomplicating this problem. Can you tell us exactly where you want the caption? Do you want it to be floating directly under the lower right corner of the image, so that the caption ends exactly where the image does?

Comment: @tloflin: that's correct. I want the text ends where the image does.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear why you are trying to do whatever you are trying to do with the caption. Does galleria_wrapper have only one image in it? It sounds like you have a fixed width galleria_wrapper and you want the caption at the bottom right of the photo wherever it is. If so, I'd wrap the image and caption inside another div, center that div within the galleria_wrapper, and text-align right the caption.

Comment: This is essentially the correct answer. You should wrap your div and caption in another div, and right-align the caption within that. You may need to set `overflow:auto;` on the wrapping div to make sure it's the same width as the image.

Answer (score 1):

Put that code inline with the .caption element.

```
<div class="caption" style="padding-right: XXpx;">caption text</div>
```

Your question is not really clear and there is a better solution, but your full markup/demo page would be needed.

**UPDATE**

Just add the span to the galleria_wrapper div and then set text align right.

```
<div class="galleria_container">
  <div class="galleria_wrapper">
    <div style="text-align: right;">
      <img id="image" src="strangers/010.jpg" class="replaced" onload="resizeToMax(this.id)" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <span class="caption">Moscow Region, late 1980-s</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Demo is here: http://lomoportfolio.com/strangers.html
Caption will be taken from the "title" text of each image (currently empty). JavaScript processing this html is here: http://lomoportfolio.com/trunk/jquery.galleria.js

Current css (caption is placed to the absolutely wrong place) is here: http://lomoportfolio.com/trunk/galleria.css

Comment: Demo of OK placement: http://lomoportfolio.com/strangers.html#strangers/010.jpg


Demo of the wrong placement (because of fixed padding-right for caption): http://lomoportfolio.com/strangers.html#strangers/150.jpg

Comment: @durilai: would you, please, take a look at http://lomoportfolio.com/trunk/jquery.galleria.js — I can't figure out where in that JavaScript file I should insert that [style="text-align: right;"] and what to change to include span into "galleria_wrapper" instead of it being part of "galleria_container".

Comment: There is some work to be done with that library. You will need to removed how it is currently adding that span and instead add a div around the image and insert the span to that div.

Comment: @durilai: by the way, the code how you wrote it: [<div class="galleria_wrapper" style="text-align: right;">] will move to the right both picture and the caption. I need to leave picture horizontally centered.

Comment: You are right, I updated my answer to show what I meant. You need to add an additional container that has the same width as the image.

Answer (score 0):

To access programatically to the padding-right, the object property is 
`object.style.paddingRight`.

Often, the true size of an object is in px. 
So when you get its width prpoerty remove the 'px' at the end of the string before doing a parseInt or parseFloat on it.

So your function becomes:

```
var objs = document.getElementsByClass('caption'); //Is it one of your functions?
for(var index =0;index<objs.length;index++){
   objs[index].style.paddingRight = 
    ( parseInt(document.getElementByName('galleria_wrapper').offsetWidth) - 
    parseInt(document.getElementById('image').offsetWidth )/2))+"px";
}
```